# How to simulate a dataset with a binary target in proportions determined 'a-priori'?

Tags: math, statistics, simulation, logistic-regression

Can someone tell me what is the best way to simulate a dataset with a binary target?

I understand the way in which a dataset can be simulated but what I'm looking for is to determine 'a-priori' the proportion of each class. What I thought was to change the intercept to achieve it but I couldn't do it and I don't know why. I guess because the average is playing a trick on me.

```
set.seed(666)
x1 = rnorm(1000)       
x2 = rnorm(1000)

p=0.25 # <<< I'm looking for a 25%/75%
mean_z=log(p/(1-p))

b0 = mean( mean_z - (4*x1 + 3*x2)) # = mean_z - mean( 2*x1 + 3*x2)
z = b0 + 4*x1 + 3*x2  # = mean_z - (4*x1 + 3*x2)  + (4*x1 + 3*x2) = rep(mean_z,1000)
mean( b0 + 4*x1 + 3*x2 ) == mean_z # TRUE!!

pr = 1/(1+exp(-z))     
y = rbinom(1000,1,pr)  
mean(pr)  # ~ 40% << not achieved
table(y)/1000
```

What I'm looking for is to simulate the typical "logistic" problem in which the binary target can be modeled as a linear combination of features.

These 'logistic' models assume that the log-odd ratio of the binary variable behaves linearly. That means:

```
log (p / (1-p)) = z = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 where p = prob (y = 1)
```

Going back to my sample code, we could do, for example: z = 1.3 + 4 * x1 + 2 * x2 , but the probability of the class would be a result. Or instead we could choose coefficient b0 such that the probability is (statistically) similar to the one sought :

```
log (0.25 / 0.75) = b0 + 4 * x1 + 2 * x2
```

This is my approach, but there may be betters

Answer (score 0):

I gather that you are considering a logistic regression model, right? If so, one way to generate a data set is to create two Gaussian bumps and say that one is class 1 and the other is class 0. Then generate 25 items from class 1 and 75 items from class 0. Then each generated item plus its label is a datum or record or whatever you want to call it.

Obviously you can choose any proportions of 1's and 0's. It is also interesting to make the problem "easy" by making the Gaussian bumps farther apart (i.e. variances smaller in comparison to difference of means) or "hard" by making the bumps overlapping (i.e. variances larger compared to difference of means).

EDIT: In order to make sample data which correspond exactly to a logistic regression model, just make the variances of the two Gaussian bumps the same. When the variances (by this I mean specifically the covariance matrix) are the same, the surfaces of equal posterior class probability are planes; when the covariances are different, the surfaces of equal probability are quadratics. This is a standard result which will appear in many textbooks. I also have some notes online about this, which I can locate if it will help.

Aside from generating the two classes separately and then merging the results into one set, you can also sample from a single distribution over `x`, plug `x` into a logistic regression model with some weights (which you choose by any means you wish), and then use the resulting output as a probability for a coin toss. This method isn't guaranteed to output proportions that correspond exactly to prior class probabilities.

Comment: Thank Robert ! Take a new look on my question, I've edited it in order to be clearer

Comment: @c0chi OK, I've added some more to my answer, hope this helps.